# GamesNativeSDK Not authorizing: no client

Tags: android-ndk, google-play-services

I upgraded my google-play-services_lib that comes with:
Google Play services Rev28 (as installed by android SDK installer.)

Since upgrading, my NDK based app will now fail to login with this on the device log:

```
I/GamesNativeSDK(  322): Connecting to Google Play...
E/GamesNativeSDK(  322): Not authorizing: no client.
```

Did the latest Google Play services upgrade break the NDK based apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New service lib needs android-support-v4.jar inside android sdk/extras/android/support/v4.  Link your project with it should help: I experienced the problem, and linked it in, much better.

Comment: Is this still the correct lib to include? Now, v17 of android support is available.